# Geometry Nodes: Get object to follow a midpoint of a certain edge of another object (like parenting)

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

I have an Object Info -node with an object called 'Plane' inside it.

The Plane's origin is at one of its edges.

What's the most efficient way to have a duplicate of that object, but positioned to certain edge (by setting a specific edge index could work?) and so that the duplicate-Plane keeps the position if the original Plane object is rotated, scaled or translated?

Maybe these new Blender 3.4 nodes could be used?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

AH! Found one way, maybe not so optimal hmmm...

[image]

[image]